# Automatically push a Git (github) branch to to Visual studio online

Tags: git, github, tfs

Is there a native tool that is pushing all commits of a branch or any commits from GitHub to Visual studio Online without having to do anything manually?

Workflow:

I develop locally my application. 
I push it to GitHub
"Something" push it to Visual studio online

Basically it would create a copy then build + deploy it on Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to set up a post push [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for git, as long as there is a command line or Soap API to perform a Visual Studio Online push, or even trigger **it** to pull from git, and build then the post commit hook, *(commonly written in python)*, can do it.

A little online research shows that there is an [API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits) that allows linking Visual Studio Online with git for VS Team Services and TFS accounts.